# resize images based on a percent value

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I am working a code to resize some images within a div when the window resizes. I think if you read the code you will understand:

```
$('img').each( function() {
    var image = $(this);
    var imagewidth = $(this).width();
    $.event.add(window, 'load', resizeFrame);
    $.event.add(window, 'resize', resizeFrame);

    function resizeFrame() {

        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var ratio = (980/windowWidth)*100;

        if ( windowWidth <= 980 ) {
            image.width( ratio*imagewidth + '%');
        }
    }
});
```

The code does not work, the log shows some object.. and no value.

The code works somehow. The problem is that it does resize the image according to the width of the window and not as a percent of its original size.

Comment: Do you wait for the images to load before you call that ?

Comment: You have typos : windowWindth/windowWidth

Comment: I would recommend you to use media queries.

Comment: If you multiply by the image width, you certainly shouldn't have the '%'

Comment: I've made some adjustments. The images are loaded on document ready as well as this code. I need to use percent so that I can get an exact value and I need the size to keep proportions.

Comment: an anonymous function in an anonymous function...? ^^

Comment: I cannot really tell what you want to do? As the window gets smaller, the image grows?

Comment: Yes, while you resize the window under 980px, the images resize based on the ratio current/initial width of the window.

Answer (score 3):

this code has multiple issues.
frist you append N resize handler for the resize event! 
And you don't use the each function correctly

here is the cleandup code:

```
$(window).resize(function(evt) {
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var ratio = (windowWidth/980) * 100;
        $('img').each( function(i, obj) {
            var imagewidth = $(obj).width();
            if ( windowWidth <= 980 ) {
                $(obj).attr('width', ratio + '%');
            } else {
                $(obj).attr('width', '100%');
            }
        });
    });
```

html:

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
                <img src="image.png">
            </div>
```

for this function to work you need to determine the max width of the image in a div around the image. otherwise you have to save the original width of the image to rescale it

Comment: I don't understand what you use (i,obj) for ? Can you please explain?

Comment: sure i can ;) the each function expects a callback and passes for each iteration to parameters to this function. i = no. of iteration, obj = the current object. and i think you don't have to multiply with the imagewidth when you want to use percentige witdh

Comment: tested and updated, chooose the function you need - but still don't get the idea ^^

Comment: maybe you have to play around with ratio and imagewidth till you get the desired result, but now the event fires and resizes images ;)

Comment: ok I don't know why it does not work properly, it does something now. So if I resize/load the window under 980px, we should get a percent of the window windowWidth/980 ratio. I want the images to be resized to keep the proportions. It's that easy. I think the other function would have done something else but the previous helper deleted his answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23171/discussion-between-danny-and-mercsen)

Comment: sorry i'm a bit too tired, but i updated the answer again, now it scales an image when the screen is below 980px and restore its original value when screen width is over 980px. but you have to limit the max size by put the image into a div. we could chat tomorrow, i also could explain you how to work with data and real values.